# Narrowing conversion from char to double

Tags: c++, c++11, narrowing

Why there is a warning

> narrowing conversion from char to double

I know already that for const char there will be no warning. There are a lot of answers about that. But I would like to know, why for non-const char there is a "might-narrow" warning?

Is it possible that on some systems mantissa is not big to perfectly represent char?

```cpp
int main() {
  char c{7};
  double a{c};
}
```

> 4:13: warning: narrowing conversion of 'c' from 'char' to 'double'
>   inside { } [-Wnarrowing]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is narrowing because the standard says so.

> 7 A *narrowing conversion* is an implicit conversion
>   [...]
>   (7.3) — **from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to a floating-point type**, except where the source is a constant expression and the actual value after conversion will fit into the target type and will produce the original value when converted back to the original type [...]

Narrowing is not allowed in list-initialization. Use an explicit conversion (cast).

```
double a{static_cast<double>(c)};
```

Yes, theoretically it is allowed for `char` to be not exactly representable as `double`, e.g. when both are 32-bit types. This is contrived but the standard allows for such an implementation.

Comment: Did that mean that if we change the constant value to another constant value we may get a narrowing warning because that value will not be the same by converting forth and back?

Comment: Thanks for giving the rationale. One could still argue that *if* all possible values of the source type are exactly representable it should be allowed; but there are already so many pages in the standard...